# SuperLearner Predictions for Out-of-Sample Test Set

Tags: r, machine-learning

The `SuperLearner` package in R returns predicted values for all observations included in the training set under `SL.predict` and also returns coefficients (`coef`) that weight the different underlying algorithms to make up the SuperLearner algorithm for each fold in the cross-validation, but I cannot figure out how to use the package to get predicted values for an out-of sample test set. For example, below is the toy example from their [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SuperLearner/SuperLearner.pdf). The only change I have made is to add a hold out test set X2 and Y2 at the end. How do I estimate predicted values for this out-of-sample test set based on the SuperLearner model from the training set? How can I save the model results so that I can estimate predicted values in the future based on this same model?

```
library(SuperLearner)


set.seed(23432)
## training set
n <- 500
p <- 50
X <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow = n, ncol = p)
colnames(X) <- paste("X", 1:p, sep="")
X <- data.frame(X)
Y <- X[, 1] + sqrt(abs(X[, 2] * X[, 3])) + X[, 2] - X[, 3] + rnorm(n)
# build Library and run Super Learner
SL.library <- c("SL.glm", "SL.randomForest", "SL.gam", "SL.polymars", "SL.mean")
## Not run:
test <- CV.SuperLearner(Y = Y, X = X, V = 10, SL.library = SL.library,
  verbose = TRUE, method = "method.NNLS")
test
summary(test)
# Look at the coefficients across folds
coef(test)
## End(Not run)

###Added Test Set
X2 <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow = n, ncol = p)
colnames(X2) <- paste("X", 1:p, sep="")
X2 <- data.frame(X2)
Y2 <- X2[, 1] + sqrt(abs(X2[, 2] * X2[, 3])) + X2[, 2] - X2[, 3] + rnorm(n)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `predict` method for `SuperLearner` objects
after estimating your model on all the data
(`CV.SuperLearner` estimates the model on several subsets of the data,
not the whole data).

```
r <- SuperLearner(Y = Y, X = X, SL.library = SL.library, verbose = TRUE, method = "method.NNLS")
plot( Y2 ~ predict(r, newdata=X2)$pred )
```

Comment: My understanding of SuperLearner's strength is that it weights the underlying algorithms based on their out-of-sample performance in the v-fold cross-validation within the training set. It cannot do that if you do not split the training set into multiple folds with `CV.SuperLearner`.

Comment: The cross-validation is done automatically when you call `SuperLearner`: all algorithms are run on `V` folds, the results are used to compute the weights, all algorithms are then run on the whole data, and their forecasts are weighted accordingly. `CV.SuperLearner` adds another level of cross-validation, only useful if you want to measure how well the whole algorithm works on your data.

Comment: Thanks, in re-reading the manual I see now that the default is V = 10 for the `SuperLearner` function, specified in the default of the argument for `cvControl`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, by using your hold out sample in the CV.SuperLearner procedure.
In this procedure, the trained SuperLearner is being evaluated using the cross validation methodology.
Hope this helps
-Remko-