# Incorporating cross validation in stepwise regression in R

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

I have a dataset of 162 observations with a 151 different variables and I would like to perform stepwise regression on it, but to also do 10 fold cross validation on it. I have used the package DAAG before in order to perform 10 fold cross validation with multiple linear regression and was able to use one of its formulas:-

```
CVlm(df = data, seed=1500, m = 10, form.lm = formula(RT..seconds.~.,), printit=TRUE)
```

I was wondering whether the package supported the same thing but with stepwise regression? I've had a look through it's pdf but was unable to find anything.

I know that I can perform stepwise regression using the MASS package by doing

```
step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="both")
```

but can't see how I can incorporate 10-fold CV into the equation.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `caret` package.

Answer (score 5):

The `SuperLearner` package supports v-fold cross validation of stepwise regression.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that. I've just had a look at the SuperLearner package but there isn't much help about how to construct it for stepwise. I'm quite confused with the PDF as well. I understand that you need to do:-

'CV.SuperLearner(Y, X, V = 20, family = gaussian(), SL.library,
method = "method.NNLS", id = NULL, verbose = FALSE,
control = list(saveFitLibrary = FALSE), cvControl = list(),
obsWeights = NULL, saveAll = TRUE, parallel = "seq")'

but where and how do you specify you want to use stepwise regression in this?

Comment: Also how do I specify the Y and X values, as in all the other regression algorithms I would simply just do RT..seconds.~., and specify what my data set is.

Comment: You need to define `SL.library`. If you use  `listWrappers()` you will see all available algorithms, which includes `SL.step`. So if you just want that `SL.library <- c("SL.step")`. Source code is [here](https://github.com/ecpolley/SuperLearner/blob/master/R/SL.step.R). You may also find the code from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680529/superlearner-predictions-for-out-of-sample-test-set) helpful.